# The exe in my console app Debug folder can't find dll, which dubugging from Visual Studio 2013 finds without issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl, exe, visual-studio-debugging

I'm working on a C++ SDL project and I have no problems debugging in Visual Studio, but when trying to run the exe from the debug folder directly it tells me the program could not be started because SDL2.dll is could not be found.  It is in the same directory as the exe, so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb for having asked this.  All I had to do was change the runtime library from "Multi-threaded DLL" to "Multi-threaded Debug".